# Prestashop - Default Paypal tab

Tags: paypal, prestashop

I have Paypal module in my Prestashop 1.4, and I use it for Paypal + CB ; but when the user checks out, he's redirected to the tab "I have a Paypal account". I would like to redirect it directly to the tab "I don't have a Paypal account"

Do you have an idea please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I didn't answer more quickly ; I finally find the solution myself, don't remember exactly the file location but here's the idea :

You need to modify Paypal plugin and find the LANDINGPAGE parameter ; just modify it to be "Billing"

More informations : https://cms.paypal.com/fr/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_SetExpressCheckout

Answer (score 0):

To default payment by card tab (without having paypal account), you must select the Express Payment in the Paypal module from the backoffice. Once this is done, look for the file "process.php" in  "/modules/paypal/express_checkout" and edit line 147 (in version 1.5.2 of Prestashop) where it says:

```
$ Fields ['LANDINGPAGE'] = 'Login';
```

You change it by:

```
$ Fields ['LANDINGPAGE'] = 'Billing';
```

I hope you serve them.
Greetings.